# Backbone: fetching from URL in router gets undefined, but it works when collection gets JSON from a variable

Tags: json, backbone.js, fetch

From a JSON stored in a variable I can get the name of the current id from a router function called `show: function(id)`. However, when I fetch collection from an URL instead of using a JSON variable I get an undefined TypeError.

```
console.log(this.collection.get(id).get('name'));
```

What I have seen is that when I use a JSON variable the `show function` works fine, but when I fetch from URL, `show function` executes after `fetch` succeed.

What I am doing wrong? Why fetching from URL gets undefined? How can I make it work?

The following code is fictional, it only shows the relevant part of my code. See the two cases at the end of the code block.
[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pprczoux/2/)

```
// Data 1 with variable
var heroes = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "Batman"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "Superman"},
];

// Data 2 from url: http://example.com/heroes.json
[
  {"id": "1", "name": "Batman"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "Superman"},
];

HeroesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: HeroesModel,
  url: 'http://example.com/heroes.json'
});

HeroesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  // I use two shows to graphic this example
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    ':id': 'show'
  },

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.collection = options.collection;
    this.collection.fetch();
    // this.collection.fetch({async:false}); this fixes my problem, but I heard it is a bad practice
  },

  index: function() {

  },

  show: function(id) {
    console.log(this.collection.get(id).get('name'));
        // Case #1: When Collection loads from a Variable 
        // id 1 returns: 'Batman'

        // Case #2: When Collection fetchs from URL, id 1 returns:
        // TypeError: this.collection.get(...) is undefined 
  }

});

// Case #1: collection loads JSON from a variable
var heroesCollection = new HeroesCollection(heroes);
// Case #2: collection loads JSON with fetch in router's initialize
// var heroesCollection = new HeroesCollection();
var heroesRouter = new HeroesRouter({collection: heroesCollection});
```

Comment: How/when does your application navigate to a route matching `:id` ..?

Comment: @TJ the common way to navigate is from an index page where each item links to its ID; another way to navigate is by pasting the exact URL with the ID.

Comment: I'm asking how/when are you doing it with the code above. if you directly type an id on the addressbar before fetch is complete obviously it won't work and you need to handle such things. Is that what you're doing? Where are you creating the view that displays the fetched data..?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. I see now your point. The fetched data is created in the index action. Maybe I should force the user to navigate to index first before going to show.

Comment: Usually, if you have a route that displays a particular model info, the route can fetch the data for that model before initializing the view, or instead the view can fetch the model data before rendering. For this your backend should have a service that sends single items info rather than a list of all items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  It's been awhile, but this seems like a better approach to what you are trying to achieve.  The basic concept is that once you navigate to your show route, it will execute show.  This method will create a new, empty collection, and then fetch the data for it.  Along with that, we pass in a success method (as François illustrated) which will execute when the request is finished with the JSON (which creates a collection of Heros).

I believe the reason you were running into the issue with the remote data is that you were trying to access this.collection before it was populated with data from the request.

You have to remember the request is asynchronous, which mean code execution continues while the request is processing.

```
HeroesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: HeroesModel,
  url: 'http://example.com/heroes.json'
});

HeroesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    ':id': 'show'
  },

  index: function() {

  },

  show: function(id) {
    this.herosCollection = new HerosCollection();
    this.herosCollection.fetch({
      success: function(collection, response, options) {
        console.log(this.get(id).get('name'));
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Erik your solution works well, thanks; but do you think it is a good practice to fetch data by each route action? Considering I have to fetch data for index action.

Comment: Sure why not? Fetch away!  If you wan't, you can wrap your models in an API and cache locally cache your fetches if you are worried about round trips....but I don't think this is necessary

Comment: usually this is done in views not in the router. However I wouldn't say it's a bad practice. It depends how you want to organize your code. Personally I like to bind views with model by instanciating them there.

Comment: I would much rather have a "controller" and let the controller make the requests.  In my opinion, a view should be "dumb".  Just display data and react to model/collection changes that are orchestrated by the controller.  Views should just fire events, controllers should handle those.

Comment: true but there is no controller in backbone (mv* stuff..). But yeah writing real controller instead of views having this role can be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

you need to trigger the router 'show' function when the collection has ended to load. 
    this.collection.fetch({async:false}); fixes your problem because the whole javascript code is waiting (async:false) the ajax call to be ended before going further.

The other and best solution is to wait that your collection is fetched before you try to use the results.

Basically:

```
MyCollection.fetch({
   success: function(model, reponse) {
      // do wtv you want with the result here or trigger router show method...
   }
});
```